# How to view the value of a Metashape Application attribute that displays in angle brackets < >

Tags: python

How do I access the value of an object attribute that displays in angle brackets like: `<attribute 'version' of 'Metashape.Metashape.Application' objects>`?

Specifically, I am using the [Metashape Python module](https://www.agisoft.com/downloads/installer/) and run the following lines within an interactive Python session:

```
import Metashape
a = Metashape.Application
a.version
```

and this is when I get

```
<attribute 'version' of 'Metashape.Metashape.Application' objects>
```

I've tried `print(a.version)` and get the same output.

According to the module [reference doc](https://www.agisoft.com/pdf/metashape_python_api_2_0_0.pdf), this attribute should be a string, so I'm confused why it can't just be displayed as a string.

Comment: Here, `a` is the Metashape.Application *class*. What do you get if you do `o.version` where `o` is an *instance* of that class?

Comment: Ah yes @slothrop and @OneMadGypsy are both right, and it was indeed a Python newbie error. I should have called `a = Metashape.Application()` instead of `a = Metashape.Application`. Also, it is right that `Metashape.app` was already defined. With both approaches I'm able to access/print the version as a string. Thank you.

Comment: Cf. `int.real` -> `<attribute 'real' of 'int' objects>` vs `int().real` -> `0`

Comment: I intended this to be a more general Python question about objects and attributes (and my original title conveyed that) but the answers and others' edits to my post have made this Metashape-specific and focused on the fact that an instance of the Application class already exists in the Metashape module. Nonetheless the answers solved my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs:

> An instance of Application object can be accessed using Metashape.app
> attribute, so there is usually no need to create additional instances
> in the user code.

so...

```
import Metashape
print(Metashape.app.version)
```

If you want to do it your way, you need to instance `Application`.

```
import Metashape
app = Metashape.Application()
print(app.version)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aiming to understand the python logic behind my issue, and the second half of your answer addresses it. The first half is a handy shortcut specific to my Metashape example. My issue was a basic confusion about a class vs an instance of a class. I should have called `a = Metashape.Application()` instead of `a = Metashape.Application`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Metashape.app.version, which returns x.x.x version number as a string, you can use Metashape.version of Metashape.Version() type, this approach allows to get .major, .minor, .micro and .build numbers:

[in] Metashape.version

[out] 2.0.1

[in] Metashape.version.major, Metashape.version.minor, Metashape.version.micro, Metashape.version.build

[out] (2, 0, 1, 15925)

Answer (score 1):

That Docs said:

> ...An instance of Application object can be accessed using Metashape.app attribute...

So you can print the value of `version` use `Metashape.app`

```py
import Metashape

a = Metashape.app
print(a.version)
```